# hAxis.slantedText or legend repositioning with Google Material Column Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, material-design

SlantedText doesn't seem to work although the classic chart could do that. (This is the feature which rotates the labels on the horizontal axis a little, so they can fit onto the figure even when there are fairly enough columns). Is that something which is not implemented yet in the beta Material Charts, or am I doing something wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
<div id="top_x_div" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Move', 'Percentage'],
      ["King's pawn (e4)", 44],
      ["Queen's pawn (d4)", 31],
      ["Knight to King 3 (Nf3)", 12],
      ["Queen's bishop pawn (c4)", 10],
      ['Other', 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Chess opening moves',
      width: 500,
      chart: { subtitle: 'popularity by percentage' },
      hAxis: { slantedText: true },
      "hAxis.slantedText": true
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/cjs3atnp/3/

As you can see I tried multiple ways to set that flag. I just don't want to abandon the Material charts because they look nicer.
Classic charts working:

https://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/cjs3atnp/4/

Comment: Legend repositioning also doesn't work. I guess it's beta? Or the option is in a different place???

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is still not implemented. Material Charts are in beta. Trend lines are not functional either as of now.

I indicate Material vs Classic only features in my related GitHub repo: https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/GoogleChartsTalk